# Using a insertion sort function for two dimensional array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

One of the functions I am doing uses a insertion sort for a two dimensional array with 2 rows and 12 columns. The first row is for student IDs, so there are 12 students total. The second row has the corresponding GPA for each student. I am not sure how to come up with an insertion sort to sort the GPA numbers in ascending order. Any help would be awesome!

I have this so far.

```
void insertionSort(double avg[][COLS])
{
int current = 1;
int last = COLS - 1;
int temp;
int walker;
int row = 1;

while (current <= last)
{
    temp = avg[row][current];
    walker = current - 1;
    while (walker >= 0
        && temp < avg[row][walker])
    {
        avg[row][walker+1] = avg[row][walker];
        walker = walker - 1;
    }

    avg[row][walker+1] = temp;
    current = current + 1;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with the sort you have made ? it seems to be a correct insertion sort?

Comment: Are you against the idea to use [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: My question really is why this is a two dimensional array.  Student ID's are alphanumeric, GPA's are floating point.  Who came up with such an idea to make a 2d array out of two distinct types?

Comment: @m7mdbadawy when I try to output the numbers, the numbers are not correct. The number 2.00 shows up for all of them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the student ID are just numbered from 1 through 12. Student 1 has student ID of 1, student 2 has ID 2, etc.

Comment: @YSC yes, I am not allowed to use `std::sort()`

Comment: @Mark *the student ID are just numbered from 1 through 12. Student 1 has student ID of 1, student 2 has ID 2, etc* -- That doesn't take away from this setup being highly unorthodox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `temp` variable is declared as an int it should be double also you should swap the ids too

```
void insertionSort(double avg[][COLS])
{
    int current = 1;
    int last = COLS - 1;
    double temp;//this was an int
    int walker;
    int row = 1;

    while (current <= last)
    {
        temp = avg[row][current];
        walker = current - 1;
        while (walker >= 0
                && temp < avg[row][walker])
        {
            avg[row][walker+1] = avg[row][walker];
            avg[row-1][walker+1] = avg[row-1][walker];//swap the id of two students
            walker = walker - 1;
        }

        avg[row][walker+1] = temp;
        avg[row-1][walker+1] = temp;
        current = current + 1;
    }
}
```